# Remove element from last level of nested list C# LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have an entity with multiple levels of nested lists - Is there a way to remove element from last level using LINQ (without any nested foreach) - remove Dosage with id = X from strength with id  = Y from route with id = Z from drug with id = Q? (assume X Y Z Q are ints)
I've provided my entity structure below.

```
var entity: List<Drug>;
Drug {
    int id;
    List<Route> routes;
}

Route {
    int id;
    List<Strength> strengths;
}

Strength {
    int id;
    List<Dosage> dosages;
}

Dosage {
    int id;
}
```

Comment: If you want to find element inside of a single list, you have to loop through the list. so I don't know why you don't want to use `foreach` to remove a item. if you wanted to just select the item then you search for the item using select

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
drugList.Where(x => x.id == Q).FirstOrDefault().routes.Where(x => x.id == Z).FirstOrDefault().strengths.Where(x => x.id == Y).FirstOrDefault().dosages.RemoveAt(X);
```

With the Q,Z,Y,X as the index values from your post.

Comment: Q, Z and Y aren't indexes ;) (naming thing)

Comment: The value for each id, that's what I ment :)